# Why won't this jquery get command save dynamic ui sortable list?

Tags: php, jquery, get, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to save the order of my jquery ui sortable list to the server. I am loading my list from an external file when the user clicks a tab, then adding a checkbox to each list item. The code was working fine until I put in the line to add the checkbox - now it won't save the order on the server. I can't figure out why prepend checkbox line is breaking it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Jquery to load list and add checkbox:

```
        window.onload = function() {


        var a = document.getElementById("fvsortid"); // loads slides when user clicks tab and adds checkbox

          a.onclick = function() {
          $("#sortable").load("file.xml");
          $("#sortable").load("file.xml", function(){
          $('<input type="checkbox"/>').prependTo('#sortable li');
          });
}    

        }
```

Jquery to update order:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $('#sortable').html();
            $.get('reorder.php', {order:newOrder});
            alert("New order saved to server");
        }
    });

});
```

Reorder.php:

```
   <?php
    $items = $_GET['order'];
    $items = "<body>\n$items\n</body>";
    file_put_contents('file.xml', $items);
    ?>
```

Comment: try using `$('#sortable li').prepend('<input type="checkbox" />');`

Comment: thanks for the reply...but still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you prepend an `input` element to a `li` element, the input will end up as a child element of `ul`, which is invalid. Perhaps you can prepend to another element, or wrap the `input` in a `li` element?